# How to color overlay non transparent SKSpriteNode texture parts withs Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, pixel-shader

I am making a isometric game using Swift and Sprite Kit.
I am rethinking my approach about coloring buildings before they are build.

Like in every game, before user builds an object, he has to move it to the free plot, and by moving it, node will change color from green to red, if the object can or cannot be placed.

Here are some pictures for clarification:

[image] [image]

What I am doing right now, as i am prety new in Sprite Kit:

I make one SKNode - parent

I make 3 nodes and add them to a parent node. Those 3 nodes contain regular building image, red building image and green building image.

If building should be colored red, I hode nodes containing green and regular images. if it needs to be green, I hide other two and sme goes for regular.

My main question is this:

Can I have only regular node, with regular image, and somehow overlay it with green or red color (but only overlay non transparent image parts?
I was thinking abut using **Pixel Shader** but I'm not sure if it's the right tool.

If I cannot do that my next question is: Is this 3 nodes in a parent approach a good one or it's better to change the image of one node, depending if I need to show regular green or red object image?

Comment: Have you tried setting the sprite's `color` property to red or green and the `colorBlendFactor` to 1?

Comment: Becareful with colorBlend though,  I do not think that alpha blending is working correctly.  If you have a blue image(ABGR) (1,1,0,0) and try to blend it with green (1,0,1,0) you should be getting cyan. because alpha blending is SRCrgb*SRCa + DSTrgb*SRCa , so we should be getting (1,1,1,0), but instead I get a dark green (1,0,0.2,0).  If I merge blue and red,  I end up getting black, If I merge blue and cyan, I get blue

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the docs show Apple uses RGBA format not ABGR. Also, where did you get that expression for alpha blending?

Comment: @Epsilon I was explaining the way my numbers were formatted, not the way the numbers are ordered at the programming level.  As for the definition, https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skblendmode/1483074-alpha

Comment: @Epsilon, also I am pretty sure that ios is little endian,  so ABGR would be correct since R would be the lowest part in the word,  they just use RGBA to avoid confusion

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that link points to a description not an equation. I've never seen colors blended using `SRCrgbSRCa + DSTrgbSRCa` before.

Comment: there are different methods to define the alpha blending,  source alpha, 1 - source alpha, destination alpha, 1-destination alpha, among others

Comment: @Epsilon, regardless of the math, logically, blending blue and red should not get black, while blue and green get a very dark green using alpha blending

Comment: If you decide to implement this as a simple color manipulation shader, please have a look at my blog post on doing a simple shader under sprite kit, this example shows desaturation applied to a node: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post19_spritekit_bw_shader

Comment: I would recommend doing it as a shader,  you get more control and you know the gpu is doing the work not the cpu